# Is there a way to catch all rows if there is no status = 0 in table mgevent? SELECT and TABLE attached

Tags: mysql

I have three tables,

```
    lagerevent
    mgevent
    mitglied
```

lagerevent holds `evid evname evdatvon evdatbis status`

mgevent holds `mgnr evid status`

mitglied holds `mgnr vname nname an`

Every `mgevent.evid` can have several `mgevent.mgnr` with three different possible `mgevent.status` which are 0, 1 and 2.
Every `mgevent.mgnr`can have only one `mgevent.status` with one `mgevent.evid`

`lagerevent`and `mitglied`is only used to get the names of the events and the name of mitglied ...

The following SELECT dows work perfect as long as all three stati are available in `mgevent` BUT do not catch a event which has only two stati `mgevent.status'

```
     SELECT 
         e1.evdatvon,
         e1.evdatbis,
         e1.evname,
         mg1.status,
         GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT mi1.vname
             ORDER BY mi1.vname
             SEPARATOR ', '),
         mg2.status,
         GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT mi2.vname
             ORDER BY mi2.vname
             SEPARATOR ', '),
         mg3.status,
         GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT mi3.vname
             ORDER BY mi3.vname
             SEPARATOR ', ')
     FROM
         lagerevent AS e1,
         mgevent AS mg1,
         mgevent AS mg2,
         mgevent AS mg3,
         mitglied AS mi1,
         mitglied AS mi2,
         mitglied AS mi3
     WHERE
         e1.status = 1 AND e1.evid = mg1.evid
             AND e1.evid = mg2.evid
             AND e1.evid = mg3.evid
             AND mg1.status = 0
             AND mg2.status = 1
             AND mg3.status = 2
             AND mg1.mgnr = mi1.mgnr
             AND mg2.mgnr = mi2.mgnr
             AND mg3.mgnr = mi3.mgnr
     GROUP BY mg1.evid , mg1.status
     ORDER BY e1.evid;`
```

lagerevent

```
     evid   evname                                              evdatvon    evdatbis    status  
     000001 Mittelaltermarkt Mendener Frühling und Heerlager    2019-05-04  2019-05-05  0   
     000002 Mittelaltermarkt Hagen blüht auf und Heerlager      2019-05-10  2019-05-12  1   
     000003 Historienspiele Festung Ehrenbreitstein 2019        2019-05-30  2019-06-02  1   
     000004 16. Broicher Pfingst Spektakulum Schloß Broich      2019-06-06  2019-06-10  1   
     000005 2. Schloss Walbecker Spektakel                      2019-07-18  2019-07-21  1   
     000006 Schaephuysen                                        2019-08-29  2019-09-01  1   
     000007 Ritterfest zu Gangelt 2019                          2019-09-04  2019-09-08  1
```

mgevent

```
     mgnr evid  status  
     001    000001  0   
     002    000001  0   
     003    000001  2   
     004    000001  0   
     005    000001  2   
     006    000001  2   
     007    000001  0   
     008    000001  2   
     009    000001  2   
     010    000001  0   
     011    000001  1   
     012    000001  0   
     013    000001  0   
     014    000001  0   
     015    000001  1   
     016    000001  1   
     017    000001  0   
     018    000001  0   
     019    000001  1   
     020    000001  0   
     021    000001  0   
     022    000001  1   
     023    000001  0   
     024    000001  0   
     001    000002  0   
     002    000002  1   
     003    000002  2   
     004    000002  2   
     005    000002  0   
     006    000002  2   
     007    000002  0   
     008    000002  2   
     009    000002  2   
     010    000002  0   
     011    000002  1   
     012    000002  1   
     013    000002  1   
     014    000002  1   
     015    000002  1   
     016    000002  1   
     017    000002  0   
     018    000002  1   
     019    000002  1   
     020    000002  0   
     021    000002  0   
     022    000002  1   
     023    000002  0   
     024    000002  1   
     001    000003  2   
     002    000003  1   
     003    000003  1   
     004    000003  2   
     005    000003  2   
     006    000003  1   
     007    000003  1   
     008    000003  1   
     009    000003  2   
     010    000003  1   
     011    000003  1   
     012    000003  1   
     013    000003  1   
     014    000003  1   
     015    000003  1   
     016    000003  1   
     017    000003  1   
     018    000003  1   
     019    000003  1   
     020    000003  1   
     021    000003  1   
     022    000003  1   
     023    000003  1   
     024    000003  1   
     001    000004  0   
     002    000004  0   
     003    000004  1   
     004    000004  2   
     005    000004  0   
     006    000004  1   
     007    000004  1   
     008    000004  1   
     009    000004  2   
     010    000004  1   
     011    000004  1   
     012    000004  1   
     013    000004  1   
     014    000004  1   
     015    000004  1   
     016    000004  1   
     017    000004  0   
     018    000004  1   
     019    000004  1   
     020    000004  1   
     021    000004  0   
     022    000004  1   
     023    000004  0   
     024    000004  1   
     001    000005  0   
     002    000005  0   
     003    000005  2   
     004    000005  2   
     005    000005  0   
     006    000005  2   
     007    000005  2   
     008    000005  2   
     009    000005  2   
     010    000005  1   
     011    000005  1   
     012    000005  1   
     013    000005  1   
     014    000005  1   
     015    000005  1   
     016    000005  1   
     017    000005  1   
     018    000005  1   
     019    000005  1   
     020    000005  0   
     021    000005  0   
     022    000005  1   
     023    000005  0   
     024    000005  1            
     001    000006  0   
     002    000006  0   
     003    000006  2   
     004    000006  2   
     005    000006  2   
     006    000006  2   
     007    000006  0   
     008    000006  2   
     009    000006  2   
     010    000006  1   
     011    000006  1   
     012    000006  1   
     013    000006  1   
     014    000006  1   
     015    000006  1   
     016    000006  1   
     017    000006  0   
     018    000006  1   
     019    000006  1   
     020    000006  0   
     021    000006  2   
     022    000006  1   
     023    000006  2   
     024    000006  1   
     001    000007  1   
     002    000007  0   
     003    000007  1   
     004    000007  1   
     005    000007  1   
     006    000007  1   
     007    000007  1   
     008    000007  1            
     009    000007  1   
     010    000007  1   
     011    000007  0   
     012    000007  1   
     013    000007  1   
     014    000007  1   
     015    000007  1   
     016    000007  1   
     017    000007  2   
     018    000007  1   
     019    000007  1   
     020    000007  1   
     021    000007  2   
     022    000007  1   
     023    000007  2   
     024    000007  1
```

mitglied

```
     mgnr vname         nname           an  
     001     Andre          Rebig           Herr    
     002     Anja           Klocke          Frau    
     003     Ann-Christin   Wystrach        Frau    
     004     Heike          Spiller         Frau    
     005     Marc           Hansen          Herr    
     006     Martina        Schilling       Frau    
     007     Nadine         Zilius          Frau    
     008     René           Blumenstein     Herr    
     009     Stefan         Hansen          Herr    
     010     Tamara         Pingel          Frau    
     011     Thorsten       Meier           Herr    
     012     Annalisa       Scheffel        Frau    
     013     Andreas        Enning          Herr    
     014     Anke           Enning-Neuhaus  Frau    
     015     Bianca         Boy             Frau    
     016     Christian      Borchert        Herr    
     017     Florian        Weißenberg      Herr    
     018     Inga           Aretz           Frau    
     019     Jens           Starick         Herr    
     020     Kati           Skrubel         Frau    
     021     Lisa           Roth            Frau    
     022     Markus         Kaut            Herr    
     023     Robert         Meyer           Herr    
     024     Sascha         Aretz           Herr
```

Output from the SELECT:

```
     +------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     | evdatvon   | evdatbis   | evname                                          | status | GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT mi1.vname ORDER BY mi1.vname SEPARATOR ', ')                 | status | GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT mi2.vname ORDER BY mi2.vname SEPARATOR ', ')                                                                                     | status | GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT mi3.vname ORDER BY mi3.vname SEPARATOR ', ')                 |
     +------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     | 2019-05-10 | 2019-05-12 | Mittelaltermarkt Hagen blüht auf und Heerlager  |      0 | Andre, Florian, Kati, Lisa, Marc, Nadine, Robert, Tamara                           |      1 | Andreas, Anja, Anke, Annalisa, Bianca, Christian, Inga, Jens, Markus, Sascha, Thorsten                                                                 |      2 | Ann-Christin, Heike, Martina, René, Stefan                                         |
     | 2019-06-06 | 2019-06-10 | 16. Broicher Pfingst Spektakulum Schloß Broich  |      0 | Andre, Anja, Florian, Lisa, Marc, Robert                                           |      1 | Andreas, Anke, Ann-Christin, Annalisa, Bianca, Christian, Inga, Jens, Kati, Markus, Martina, Nadine, René, Sascha, Tamara, Thorsten                    |      2 | Heike, Stefan                                                                      |
     | 2019-07-18 | 2019-07-21 | 2. Schloss Walbecker Spektakel                  |      0 | Andre, Anja, Kati, Lisa, Marc, Robert                                              |      1 | Andreas, Anke, Annalisa, Bianca, Christian, Florian, Inga, Jens, Markus, Sascha, Tamara, Thorsten                                                      |      2 | Ann-Christin, Heike, Martina, Nadine, René, Stefan                                 |
     | 2019-08-29 | 2019-09-01 | Schaephuysen                                    |      0 | Andre, Anja, Florian, Kati, Nadine                                                 |      1 | Andreas, Anke, Annalisa, Bianca, Christian, Inga, Jens, Markus, Sascha, Tamara, Thorsten                                                               |      2 | Ann-Christin, Heike, Lisa, Marc, Martina, René, Robert, Stefan                     |
     | 2019-09-04 | 2019-09-08 | Ritterfest zu Gangelt 2019                      |      0 | Anja, Thorsten                                                                     |      1 | Andre, Andreas, Anke, Ann-Christin, Annalisa, Bianca, Christian, Heike, Inga, Jens, Kati, Marc, Markus, Martina, Nadine, René, Sascha, Stefan, Tamara  |      2 | Florian, Lisa, Robert                                                              |
     +------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

As you can see there is a missing event as there is no status = 0 in table `mgevent` for evid = 3.

I need to know how to fix this as I try for several days now to fix it but I think I have to less knowledge ...

I'm looking for something like:

`IF (there is no mgevent.status = 0 OR no mgevent.status = 1 OR no mgevent.status = 2 write 'no one')`

but IN the above SELECT ...

Have no idea how to solve this - totally blocked brain at that stage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your query.

1) You are using old-style, implicit `JOIN`s, with conditions in the `WHERE` clause. These need to be changed to explicit joins. Then, you can switch some (or all) of them to `LEFT JOIN`s to avoid filtering out records that cannot be fully joined.

2) The fields in your `GROUP BY` clause do not correspond to the non-aggregated fields in your `SELECT`. This allowed only on MySQL <= 5.7, and is not considered a good practice.

Here is a new version of your query. I turned all joins to `LEFT JOIN`s, you may want to adapt that. See [the db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7RNcdBqbXNToph5dremz7/0).

```
SELECT 
     e1.evdatvon,
     e1.evdatbis,
     e1.evname,
     mg1.status,
     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT mi1.vname ORDER BY mi1.vname SEPARATOR ', '),
     mg2.status,
     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT mi2.vname ORDER BY mi2.vname SEPARATOR ', '),
     mg3.status,
     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT mi3.vname ORDER BY mi3.vname SEPARATOR ', ')
 FROM
     lagerevent AS e1
     LEFT JOIN mgevent AS mg1  ON e1.evid = mg1.evid AND mg1.status = 0
     LEFT JOIN mgevent AS mg2  ON e1.evid = mg2.evid AND mg2.status = 1
     LEFT JOIN mgevent AS mg3  ON e1.evid = mg3.evid AND  mg3.status = 2
     LEFT JOIN mitglied AS mi1 ON mg1.mgnr = mi1.mgnr
     LEFT JOIN mitglied AS mi2 ON mg2.mgnr = mi2.mgnr
     LEFT JOIN mitglied AS mi3 ON mg3.mgnr = mi3.mgnr   
 WHERE 
     e1.status = 1
 GROUP BY 
     e1.evid,
     e1.evdatvon,
     e1.evdatbis,
     e1.evname,
     mg1.status,
     mg2.status,
     mg3.status
 ORDER BY 
     e1.evid;
```

Comment: My take on it is this: if you're using group_concat, you've already lost- but I accept that I'm alone in this view

Comment: @Strawberry... well we all have our sensitive spots -) But would you elaborate on  group_concat ? I am curious to learn.

Comment: To my way of thinking, that kind of thing belongs in the presentation layer

Comment: @GMB thanks for working on it but this SELECT does not nearly deliver the result as my one ... The point was that my SELECT does not work if one mgevent.status is not available in the table - rest works fine ... 
I tried JOINS already and they didn't help me ...

Comment: @noway : `LEFT JOIN` is the way to go for your use case. I tested the query and adapted it a little, now I believe that it produces the input that you expect... See the DB fiddle as well.

Comment: @GMB - my hero .... thank you so much for your effort. I really have to learn that again ... totally lost in my brain ... Thanks

Comment: Welcome @noway !